# Member list reveals member information on click (#1)

Tags: javascript, jquery, beginner, html

**What I'm doing?**

I'm creating a member-list where initially only the names are visible. Clicking the names reveals the member information. This is done with jQuery by adding/removing classes.

I left out the CSS with the transitions for this review.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="block-list member-list">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="block-list__link">member name</a>
        <div class="block-list__content">
            <!-- member information -->
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="block-list__link">member name</a>
        <div class="block-list__content">
            <!-- member information -->
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="block-list__link">member name</a>
        <div class="block-list__content">
            <!-- member information -->
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>if (!window.jQuery) { document.write('<script src="/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>'); }</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var blContent = $(".block-list__content");

        // If JS is disabled, the member information is visible by default
        $(blContent).addClass("hidden");

        $(".block-list__link").click(function(e) {
            // Prevent fragment identifier being added to the URL
            e.preventDefault();

            // Save the `block-list__content` which is a sibling of the clicked `block-list__link`
            var blCurrentContent = $(this).siblings(".block-list__content");
            if ($(blCurrentContent).hasClass("hidden")) {
                // Remove `visible` class from all `block-list__content`'s and add `hidden` class
                $(blContent).removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");

                // Remove the `hidden` class from the current `block-list__content` and add `visible` class
                $(blCurrentContent).removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
            } else {
                // If `block-list__link` is clicked again, add `hidden` class
                $(blCurrentContent).removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I massively don't like your class name convention, but I guess that's personal preference. I understand that you're using the `__` to denote subcomponents, but if you follow the principles below then that shouldn't be necessary. Just change your content to `.content` and your links to `.link`.

- Something that your code does that you might not be aware of is bind a click event to each   `.block-list__link` individually. While this is not a big issue when there are only three  links, it's better practice to use event delegation:

  ```
  $('.block-list').on('click', '.link', function () {

  });
  ```

  This will only bind the event once (to the parent `.block-list`), but it will only fire when one of the delegates (`.link`) is clicked.
- You should never be adding a class `onload`, that doesn't make sense and may cause flickering as the DOM loads before the JavaScript. Have the class added already in your HTML or better still, set the elements default in your CSS. If the `.content` elements are invisible by default then you need only have one add/remove class in your JavaScript. Let's use `.visible` for this.
- Regarding the hiding/showing, what `elclanrs` posted is valid, but I still don't think it's very easy to read. I'd prefer something like this, remember the `.content` blocks are invisible by default;

  ```
  var $blockList = $('.block-list'),
    $content = $('.content', $blockList);

  $blockList.on('click', '.link', function () {
     // hide the visible one
     var $justHidden = $content.filter('.visible')
       .removeClass('visible');
     // show the closest one, unless it's the one we just hid
     $(this).next('.content').not($justHidden)
       .addClass('visible');
  });
  ```

Answer (score 6):

You're double-wrapping elements in jQuery. `blContent` and `blCurrentContent` are already jQuery objects, so doing `$(blContent)` isn't necessary. It's common practice to prefix jQuery collections with a dollar sign `$`.

Other than that your code looks fine, but you could use `toggleClass` and exclude the current sibling element from the previous collection:

```
var $blContent = $('.block-list__content').addClass('hidden');

$('.block-list__link').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $content = $(this)
    .siblings('.block-list__content')
    .toggleClass('hidden visible');
  $blContent
    .not($content)
    .removeClass('visible')
    .addClass('hidden');
});
```

- Your code: http://jsbin.com/duqeb/1/edit
- Updated code: http://jsbin.com/geboq/4/edit

Comment: I'm a jQuery beginner. Wouldn't clicking a link for an already expanded div 1.) Remove `visible` and add `hidden` and then 2.) toggle it, which will remove `hidden` again and add `visible`. Therefor I won't be able to hide the divs anymore, right?

Comment: It works the same as your code, I'm not sure I understand the question...

Comment: No, it doesn't. Clicking a `block-list__link` with an already visible `block-list__content` won't hide it again. I _believe_ it adds `hidden` while removing all `visible` classes and right away toggles it back to `visible`.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that. Well it's because the line above add the class, you'd have to exclude the current sibling, see if this works as expected http://jsbin.com/geboq/2/edit and I'll update the answer

Comment: I updated the question with slightly better code, that should do.