# Member list reveals member information on click (#2)

Tags: html, css, sass

Not a follow-up, but related to [Member list reveals member information on click (#1)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/41207/35408). I now want my CSS reviewed.

**What I'm doing?**

The content in a list of members is revealed by jQuery (see review #1). Instead of having the content pop out, I'm using a transition to make this smooth. Because one can't transition to `height: auto;`, it's triggered by using `max-height: 2000px;`.

I have feeling this can be improved.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="block-list member-list">
    <li id="member-name-1">
        <a href="#member-name-1" class="block-list__link">
            <div class="block-list__thumbnail">
                <img src="member-name-1-thumbnail.jpg" alt="Thumbnail">
            </div>
            <span class="block-list__title">Member Name 1</span>
        </a>
        <div class="block-list__content">
            <p>Content area. No layout things inside. Paragraphs, lists, images.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="member-name-2">
        <a href="#member-name-2" class="block-list__link">
            <div class="block-list__thumbnail">
                <img src="member-name-2-thumbnail.jpg" alt="Thumbnail">
            </div>
            <span class="block-list__title">Member Name 2</span>
        </a>
        <div class="block-list__content">
            <p>Content area. No layout things inside. Paragraphs, lists, images.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="member-name-3">
        <a href="#member-name-3" class="block-list__link">
            <div class="block-list__thumbnail">
                <img src="member-name-3-thumbnail.jpg" alt="Thumbnail">
            </div>
            <span class="block-list__title">Member Name 3</span>
        </a>
        <div class="block-list__content">
            <p>Content area. No layout things inside. Paragraphs, lists, images.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.block-list__link {
    text-decoration: none;

    .block-list__title:after {
        /* Adding a space followed by `&raquo;` after titles inside links */
        content: "\0020" "\00BB";
    }
}

.block-list__thumbnail {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #f60;
    float: left;
}

.block-list__title {
    line-height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.block-list__content {
    overflow: hidden;

    /* Omitting vendor-prefixes for demonstration */
    transition: max-height 0.8s linear;

    height: 0;
    max-height: 0;

    &.visible {
        margin-top: 30px;
        height: 100%;
        max-height: 2000px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this popped out at me, I haven't looked at the entire code completely yet, so take this with a grain of salt please

not sure why you do this

```
<a href="#member-name-2" class="block-list__link">
   <div class="block-list__thumbnail">
       <img src="member-name-2-thumbnail.jpg" alt="Thumbnail">
   </div>
   <span class="block-list__title">Member Name 2</span>
</a>
```

I would probably write it like this instead

```
<a href="member-name-2" class="block-list__link">
    <img src="member-name-2-thumbnail.jpg" alt="Thumbnail" class="block-list__thumbnail" />
    <span class="block-list__title">Member Name 2</span>
</a>
```

I am pretty sure that you don't need that extra `div`
I think the image tag is going to act similar to the div tag, and I assume that you want to style the image and not the div anyway,  it looks more like a container for the image which I think is redundant. ( *I have been wrong before and am not afraid to admit it when someone gives me some solid evidence* )

that is the only thing that I can see right now, but I haven't spent much time looking at it either.